# How can I convert my SELECT query to an UPDATE to append to a field in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a select statement that selects all the duplicates in my table based on a certain criteria. I need to UPDATE all of these records with a field called BAD_CODES

So for example, if we have two duplicate fields called Tom, then we want to UPDATE the BAD_CODES field to append the letter 'D'.

Here is my select statement:

```
SELECT
    division, fips_county_code, last, suffix, first, title, birthdate, COUNT(*)
FROM
    WORK
GROUP BY
    division, fips_county_code, last, suffix, first, title, birthdate
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

This is what I have tried as far as my UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE WORK
 SET BAD_CODES = ISNULL(BAD_CODES, '') + 'D'
 WHERE (SELECT
    division, fips_county_code, last, suffix, first, title, birthdate, COUNT(*)
FROM
    WORK
GROUP BY
    division, fips_county_code, last, suffix, first, title, birthdate
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using `CTE`. Use `Count() Over()` Window aggregate function to count the records for each group and `update` the records when count is greater than `1`

```
WITH cte
     AS (SELECT *,
                Count(*) OVER(partition BY division, fips_county_code, last, suffix, first, title, birthdate) AS cnt
         FROM   WORK)
UPDATE cte
SET    BAD_CODES = Isnull(BAD_CODES, '') + 'D'
WHERE  cnt > 1
```

If you want to leave one record from duplicate then use `ROW_NUMBER`

```
WITH cte
     AS (SELECT *,
                Row_Number() OVER(partition BY division, fips_county_code, last, suffix, first, title, birthdate Order by (select null)) AS Rn
         FROM   WORK)
UPDATE cte
SET    BAD_CODES = Isnull(BAD_CODES, '') + 'D'
WHERE  RN > 1
```

In `Order by (select null)` replace `(Select Null)` with the column in which you to order the record and filter it from updating

Comment: This works exactly how I wanted, but my boss has changed his mind. He wants it now to leave one of the records. So if the count(*) is 2 for example we update just one of them now. It has to work for multiple though. So if there are 3 duplicates then it will leave 1 and delete the other 2.

How can I do this? I assume it has to do with cnt.

Comment: This also worked perfectly! I'd buy you a beer if I could.

Answer (score 0):

```
update w
set bad_codes='D'
from
work w
join
(SELECT
    division, fips_county_code, last, suffix, first, title, birthdate, COUNT(*)
FROM
    WORK
GROUP BY
    division, fips_county_code, last, suffix, first, title, birthdate
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
) dup
on 
dup.joinclause=w.joinclause
....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update using join:

```
update w
set w.bad_codes = isnull(bad_codes, '') + 'D' from
work w inner join (
    SELECT
    division, fips_county_code, last, suffix, first, title, birthdate, COUNT(*)
    FROM
        WORK
    GROUP BY
        division, fips_county_code, last, suffix, first, title, birthdate
    HAVING 
        COUNT(*) > 1
) w2 on w.division = w2.division
    and w.fips_county_code = w2.fips_county_code
    and w.last = w2.last
    and w.first = w2.first
    and w.birthdate = w2.birthdate
```